# How to make this Column -1?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Table, i want ALLTime - 1 !

[image: http://i.imgur.com/93nh1Zm.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KkUgfIQ.png]

My query

```
UPDATE `account_vip` 
SET `ALLTime` = `ALLTime` - 1 
WHERE `Username` = '1680316798874310' 
  and `Timer` <> '1455296400'
```

I tried that query but not work !

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: Not any error, just not work, mean that column "ALLTime don't get -1"

Comment: You want column value to be `-1` or you want to subtract 1 from the existing value? Also when you run the query how many rows are effected? (php my admin tells you this)

Comment: Actually column data type in varchar

Comment: according to your pics, `ALLTime` is `VARCHAR(999)`, so `\`ALLTime\` - 1` will not work. Either change the type to integer, or use [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: I tried change type to integer INT(4) , still not work 
0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0005 seconds.) -> http://i.imgur.com/Iut9Uzr.png

Comment: UPDATE account_vip
SET ALLTIME = ALLTIME - 1
WHERE Username = '1680316798874310'
and ALLTIME > 0 and Timer <> '1455296400'

Comment: @devpro: not work too -> http://i.imgur.com/Ue5SzmR.png

Comment: Chk r u getting records? **SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' and ALLTIME > 0 and Timer <> '1455296400'**

Comment: Yeah no records -> http://i.imgur.com/KIyPyDv.png

Comment: Than how can your update query will work bro lol...

Comment: UPDATE account_vip SET ALLTIME = ALLTIME - 1 WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' and ALLTIME > 0 and Timer = ""

Comment: That's querry not work too @@

Comment: Also chk the record SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' and ALLTIME > 0

Comment: Yeah that select record work !

Comment: I think @devpro is onto something in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376519/how-to-make-this-column-1#comment58458849_35376519). If nothing is being updated, it probably means that there is no rows that meet the conditions of `WHERE \`Username\` = '1680316798874310'  and \`Timer\` <> '1455296400'`. By looking at your image, there is only 1 row that matches the `Username`, but it matches the `Timer` value, so it would not be selected.

Comment: Good... And when u run this SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' and ALLTIME > 0 And Timer = ""

Comment: And also chk with SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' and ALLTIME > 0 and Timer IS NULL

Comment: Both of them not work sir !

Comment: @sean yes bro... If OP chk my last two query it will solve... And u know what I am trying to do... I HOPE OP WILL LEARN HOW TO DEBUG

Comment: OK... This is last query hope this will help SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Username = '1680316798874310' And Timer != '1455296400'

Comment: I added Timer for all id -> http://i.imgur.com/GEtzk6M.png

Comment: U can also chk r u getting result against this query ... SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Timer != '1455296400'

Comment: SELECT * FROM account_vip WHERE Timer = '1455296400' - this work because i added Timer for all id !

Comment: As per yur last IMG u updated all timer.. So I suggest to update any of them as 0 timer and chk my query.

Comment: I think its data type issue in timer column as well.. If value of timer column is integer than plz do not use varchar data type use integer and default 0

Comment: All your query work without Username = '1680316798874310'

Comment: It already integer @@

Comment: It means u don't have any records against this user I'd right?

Comment: Still waiting for yur response

Comment: @devpro: can you help me with this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388219/auto-update-this-column-after-24-p-m-0-00-a-m ?

Comment: But what about this question still open bro

Comment: What solution did u implement in this ??

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong column type.First change varchar to int then apply this query as it is:
UPDATE `account_vip` 
SET `ALLTime` = `ALLTime` - 1 
WHERE `Username` = '1680316798874310' 
  and `Timer` <> '1455296400'

Comment: I changed varchat to int and run your query, but nothing change !

Comment: What error you got.Are you changed ALLTime column type to INT

Answer (score 0):

Setting an operation inside the query is wrong. You must first fetch the table row and make an operation. So,

> `SELECT * from account_vip where Username = '1680316798874310'`

by doing so fetch the ALLTime column and set an operation.

```
$newALLTime = $fetch['ALLTime'] - 1;
```

then set the update query

```
'UPDATE account_vip SET ALLTime = '$newALLTIME where Username = '1680316798874310';
```

I just mean to help. Sorry don't flame me.

Comment: Update without table name?

Comment: Edited. Sorry don't flame me.

Comment: How is an operation inside the query wrong. From the docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html `If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:` *`UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;`*

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `account_vip` 
SET `ALLTime` = (SELECT `ALLTime` FROM `account_vip` WHERE `Username` = '1680316798874310' 
  and `Timer` <> '1455296400') - 1 
WHERE `Username` = '1680316798874310' 
  and `Timer` <> '1455296400'

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'account_vip' for update in FROM clause