# Auto Update this column after 24 P.M ( 0.00 A.M ) with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this column "ALLTime" ( int (4) type ) !
[image]

My query Update for it ( for all ID of account_vip table )

```
mysql_query(Update account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1);
```

Example: ALLTime column all now are 8, so after 0.00 AM, they will become 7 !

But i want it Auto Update - 1 after 24 P.M ( 0.00 A.M ) and don't get negative ( like -1, -2, ..., -n ), just working when ALLTime still >= 0 !

Comment: if you want to this automatically after 00 AM than you have set a cron job to do this.

Comment: U didn't respond yesterday on same kind of question

Comment: Md.SahadatHossain can you do that with PHP ?
devpro sorry bro, this is other kind question :(

Comment: Billy, you want this to happen every day at midnight?

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes Yes, after 24 PM ( 0.00 AM ) sir !

Comment: You should read up on [EVENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Read this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: @devpro: can you write help, my english and php very bad :(

Comment: No one here for do your job. Here you can find the way of solving but you have to do it yourself. If you not able to do it than please learn it first and than do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1 WHERE ALLTime > 0
```

will affect only rows where ALLTime is more than 0.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes i know, but I need It "Auto Update" like my post said !

Comment: In MySQL, it can not happen automatically. We need to use triggers or trigger the update from client side (for example, PHP code)

Comment: Yes, i use it with PHP, sorry i wrote didn't enough !

Comment: Please set a CRON job to run just past midnight and execute PHP code, `mysql_query(Update account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1 WHERE ALLTime > 0);`

Comment: I don't know PHP, can you help !

Comment: Please look at this example, http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysql_query.php

Comment: But how to set cron job with php, i don't know php

Comment: You set CRON jobs using your server control panel (eg, Webmin, cPanel) - given it's a Linux server. It is also possible to set up a CRON from command line, yet that's a subject of advanced Linux admin knowledge. So, if it's a Linux server, please look at your control panel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a `CRONJOB` and set schedule as you need and your query should be:

```
Update account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1 WHERE ALLTime > 0;
```

Use `ALLTime > 0;` it will not update -ve value.

Comment: IMHO, our answers are identical (smile)

Comment: Can you have me write some PHP with this !

Comment: @tom-chadaravicius yes u can say that. :)

Comment: @billy this will help u http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428